# Python script deployed successfully on heroku but gives application error

Tags: python, heroku

I made a simple website using Flask for a python course on Udemy. I followed the instructions and my files were successfully deployed on Heroku. However, when I run the app it gives an "Application Error". Here are the Heroku server logs:

```
2018-06-11T15:01:25.023293+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T15:01:24.704057+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T15:01:24.704057+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T15:01:25.023293+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T15:02:05.804977+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=abd99.herokuapp.com request_id=f1c2f7bb-ce07-441d-bb96-567b15932865 fwd="182.186.129.130" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=http
2018-06-11T15:02:07.070594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abd99.herokuapp.com request_id=3a345ccc-f833-4037-b16c-699019726b7e fwd="182.186.129.130" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=http
2018-06-11T22:02:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T22:04:00.100899+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T22:04:00.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-06-11T22:04:00.115121+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T22:04:00.100899+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 960fabc7 by user abdullahaquarius@gmail.com
2018-06-11T22:04:08.180699+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Website:app`
2018-06-11T22:04:10.005391+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-06-11T22:04:10.084997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed2018-06-11T22:04:10.084997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting2018-06-11T22:04:10.063441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-06-11T22:04:17.528748+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Website:app`
2018-06-11T22:04:19.374602+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-06-11T22:04:19.443054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-06-11T22:04:19.462628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed2018-06-11T22:05:28.316144+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=abd99.herokuapp.com request_id=a2919ecf-29bd-4b6c-a91c-f2bbf9fb1a00 fwd="182.186.129.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-11T22:05:30.238262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abd99.herokuapp.com request_id=8e9a6344-65f1-45f5-a9f6-55a8a489b54e fwd="182.186.129.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-11T22:07:15.078952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=abd99.herokuapp.com request_id=ccc23236-b62a-4057-b8f8-048e0891717e fwd="182.186.129.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-11T22:07:16.535609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=abd99.herokuapp.com request_id=edac7137-38ed-4ed9-a635-322d0b3ba15e fwd="182.186.129.130" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am new to git and Heroku so your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The error says that the `gunicorn` command was not found. Make sure that gunicorn is included in your `requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank You very much. I was also suspecting that but after you pointed out the requirements.txt, I checked it and instead of freezing the virtual pip to the text file I froze the original pip. After making the edits, the app works perfectly. Thanks